# "Practical" Claim about Hypothesis Testing of Bernoulli Distribution Parameter

Tags: probability, statistics, soft-question, hypothesis-testing, central-limit-theorem

First, let me state the original problem (in my own wording):

> Describe the decision procedure for testing the hypothesis about the parameter $p$ (success rate) of a Bernoulli distribution. The hypotheses are
>
> \begin{gather}
> H_0: p = p_0 \\
> H_1: p \ne p_0
> \end{gather}
>
> where $p_0$ is a fixed number. If $Y = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$, where $X_i \sim \text{Bernoulli}(p)$ are i.i.d., is available, describe the decision procedure based on $Y$ that will guarantee that the probability of type 1 error does not exceed $\alpha$. (Assume $n$ is large.)

The first solution without the assumption that $n$ is large:

> Find two critical values $Y_{lower}$ and $Y_{upper}$ such that $P(Y_{lower} < U < Y_{upper}) = 1 - \alpha$, where $U \sim \text{Binomial}(p_0, n)$. (There are many possible choices.) We accept $H_0$ if $Y_{lower} < Y < Y_{upper}$.

Then if $n$ is assumed large and we are allowed to approximate the distribution of $Y$ with a normal distribution, the method *simplifies* to

> Find two critical values $Z_{lower}$ and $Z_{upper}$ such that $P(Z_{lower} < U < Z_{upper}) = 1 - \alpha$ where $U \sim \mathcal N(0, 1)$. We accept $H_0$ if $Z_{lower} < Z < Z_{upper}$, where $Z = \sqrt{n}\frac{(Y/n) - p_0}{\sqrt{p_0(1-p_0)}}$.

This simplifies the problem slightly if we take the symmetric interval around the mean, i.e., $Z_{lower} = -Z_{upper}$.

**Here comes my question:**

I was told by a teacher that *in practice*, some people use
$$
\tilde Z = \sqrt n \frac{(Y/n) - p_0}{\sqrt{(Y/n)(1 - (Y/n))}}
$$
instead of $Z$. In other words, $p_0$ in the denominator of $Z = \sqrt{n}\frac{(Y/n) - p_0}{\sqrt{p_0(1-p_0)}}$ is replaced by $\hat p = \frac{Y}{n}$.

His explanation was that $\sqrt{p_0(1-p_0)}$ might not be representative of the true variance, and the sample variance $\sqrt{\hat p(1 - \hat p)}$ may be better. I don't think this reasoning is valid because we are testing the hypothesis!

However, after some reflection, I am starting to think that using $\tilde Z$ might not be such a wrong thing because we did employ the central limit approximation, and using $\tilde Z$ *might* correct the approximation in a proper way. Of course this would somewhat contradict the assumption that the problem allows you to use normal approximation, but is this kind of correction (if it's really a correction) valid to some degree?

*Why I think it might be correction in the right direction:* Suppose $\frac 12 < \hat p < p_0$. Then $\sqrt{\hat p(1 - \hat p)} > \sqrt{p_0(1 - p_0)}$, so $Z < \tilde Z < 0$, making it more probable to accept $H_0$ using $\tilde Z$ than $Z$. On the other hand, if $\frac 12 < p_0 < \hat p$, it becomes less probable to accept $H_0$ using $\tilde Z$.

Comment: Three quick comments: 
1) I was told the same thing and I remember seeing it in my textbooks that you can use either $p_0$ or $\widehat p$. 
2) Asymptotically, it shouldn't make a difference because if the null is true then $\widehat p \rightarrow p_0$ 3) There are many estimators that have the following form $\sqrt {n}(\widehat \theta - \theta_0) \stackrel{d}{\rightarrow}N(0,V)$ but $V$ cannot be simply calculated using the null and you must used some estimation i.e. $\widehat V$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When one is constructing a hypothesis test, you have to find a way to balance Type I error and Type II error the best. The problem is that Type I error and Type II error are usually inversely related (as in the case of this problem) which means that if you want decrease probability of Type I error in test you are going to increase Type II error. Thus the way we construct hypothesis tests is that we have threshold of how much probability Type I Error we will allow (since it is impossible to get it to 0), this threshold is called the significance level. From there, we can construct a test with that significance level, but has most power (i.e. power=$1-P(\textrm{Typer II Error)}$). In general as in this case, you look at test that actually achieve significance level since these test will have more power than ones that achieve lower than significance level

Now as you know when we do hypothesis testing we assume the null hypothesis is true (innocent until proven guilty) and that our test should have a probability of rejecting the null hypothesis when the null hypothesis is true equal to our significance level (i.e. $P$(Type I error)$\leq\alpha$). Now this is why $Z$ usually performs better than $\tilde Z$. Remember our highest priority is to ensure that $P(\textrm{Type I error})\leq\alpha$. Well if null hypothesis is true and we have a large enough sample size, the variance will be exactly $Var(\frac{Y}{n})=\frac{p_{o}(1-p_{o})}{n}$ instead of approximately $\frac{\hat p(1-\hat p)}{n}$. Thus since $Z$ relies on less approximations that $\tilde Z$ the $P$(Type I Error) will be closer to actually being our significance level.

The reason we even bring up $\tilde Z$ is because its a general test for sample average (which ends being a proportion in Bernoulli/Binomial situation), but since you can find exact sample variance when null hypothesis is true its not the best test to use.

Here are some resources also about Wald and Score Tests 
http://ocw.jhsph.edu/courses/methodsinbiostatisticsii/PDFs/lecture18.pdf
http://www.biostat.umn.edu/~dipankar/bmtry711.11/lecture_02.pdf

Comment: Does this mean the root cause why some people use $\tilde Z$ instead of $Z$ in this problem is because they are not aware of the fact that the variance of the Bernoulli distribution is completely determined by its mean?

Comment: That could be a possibility. One also may use a Wald test instead because for example if you are using a statistical program and you perform as hypothesis test about the mean of the data (i.e. proportion for Bernoulli) it would default to the Wald test most likely since it the program would just used that generalized test.

Comment: So I guess even with that example it has to do with looking over the fact that you can find exact variance when null is true

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Now I understand why some non-mathematicians may use Wald test instead of the more logical approach.

Comment: You're welcome. I also wondered same questions in early statistics courses when at times there were more than one type of test for same hypothesis. It can be quite confusing. Also hope that user103828 and Eupraxis1981 helped you as well because they gave great answers too

Answer (score 2):

For hypothesis testing purposes, you always use the actual null distribution, which requires no estimation. Therefore, I am suspicious of your teacher's response.

However, your teacher may have been referring to how confidence intervals are formed, in which case, you do use estimates. Your case appears to look like the beginnings of the basic "textbook" CI for the sample proportion.

However, a basic simulation of such an experiment (Monte Carlo) will show that the "practical" Z score is inferior to the normal approximation in terms of Type I error. For example, I simulated an experiment involving the sum of 50 bernoulli(p) rvs. I used the 1.96 cutoff for two sided rejection regions and then used both the "typical" and the "practical" Z values. The latter one gave a Type I error rate of 7% whilst the former only had a 4% Type I error rate, clearly better.

From a theoretical standpoint, we can compare the variance of the two Z scores:

$Var(Z)=Var\left(\sqrt{\frac{n}{p(1-p)}}(\frac{Y}{n}-p)\right)=\frac{n}{p(1-p)}Var(\frac{Y}{n})=\frac{1}{np(1-p)}(np(1-p))=1$

Now, let $\tilde Z_n=\sqrt{n}\frac{Y/n-p}{\sqrt{Y/n(1-Y/n)}}$

Asymptotically, $Var(\tilde Z_n)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow \infty}1$ due to the consistency of the estimator.

However, note that: $\forall (n<\infty)\;P(Y=n \cup Y=0)>0$ which implies that $|Var(\tilde Z_n)|=\infty\;\forall(n<\infty)$ Hence, your teacher's "practical" method has an undefined variance (in fact, I had to "rig" my simulations to conservatively treat undefined ratios as an non-rejection in order for the simulations to not run into NAN errors!)

Comment: Thank you. I am now more certain that I am not an illogical stubborn brat. The teacher was certainly referring to hypothesis testing, not the confidence interval. That is why it bothers me. May I ask what parameter $p$ did you use in your simulation? I tend to believe that when $p$ is close to $0$ or $1$, using $p$ to compute the variance may give a higher rejection rate. The situation may reverse when $p$ is close to $0.5$.
Anyway, am I right to say that your simulation suggests that my hypothesis about correcting the error is not quite right?

Comment: @Tunococ I used both 0.9 and 0.5 and got similar results in both cases, although the differences are inconsequential at p=0.5

Comment: I think I don't follow the last paragraph. Why is $Var(\tilde Z_n)$ infinity? I don't know why $P(Y \in \{0, n\}) > 0$ implies $Var(\tilde Z_n) = \infty$. (Are you talking about $Var(|\tilde Z_n|)$?)

Comment: @Tunococ because that means that $\tilde Z$ has a positive probability of being infinitely large, hence all moments will be infinite.

Comment: I really don't understand. The sentence above the last paragraph you wrote $Var(\tilde Z_n) \to 1$, but then you say $Var(\tilde Z_n) = \infty$ in the last paragraph. Are there different definitions of $\tilde Z_n$?

Comment: @Tunococ what I meant is that *asymptotically* the two should have the same variance, **but** the convergence is not *uniform*, hence for any finite $n$ the variance is infinite.

Comment: I think I know what you're saying now. Each $\tilde Z_n$ does have infinite variance. I think your statement about $Var(\tilde Z_n)$ converging to $1$ is not quite right. A more correct statement is $\tilde Z_n \xrightarrow{d} \tilde Z$ and $Var(\tilde Z) = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, using $\widehat p=\frac{Y}{n}$ instead of $p_0$ is valid (but your treacher's reason I think is incorrect). The reason that it is valid to use $\widehat p$ instead of $p_0$ is because the asymptotics are the same i.e. the hypothesis test is based on 
$$\sqrt{n}(\widehat p - p_0) \stackrel{d}{\rightarrow}N(0,p_0 (1-p_0))$$
By the continuous mapping theorem (i.e. if $z_n \stackrel{d}{\rightarrow} z$ and $g$ is some continuous function then $g(z_n) \stackrel{d}{\rightarrow} g(z)$) and Slutsky theorem (i.e. if $z_n \stackrel{d}{\rightarrow} z$ and $y_n \stackrel{p}{\rightarrow} y$ then $z_ny_n \stackrel{d}{\rightarrow} zy$ ),
$$\frac{\sqrt{n}(\widehat p - p_0)}{\sqrt{p_0 (1-p_0)}} \stackrel{d}{\rightarrow}N(0,1)$$
and 
$$\frac{\sqrt{n}(\widehat p - p_0)}{\sqrt{\widehat p (1-\widehat p)}} \stackrel{d}{\rightarrow}N(0,1)$$
Hence, asymptotically it doesn't make a difference if you use $p_0$ or $\widehat p$.

Two final points, (1) finite samples (as @Eupraxis1981 did in some simulations) may show that $p_0$ works better (especially if the true $p_0$ is far from 0.5), (2) there are many other estimators (in economics at least) that are based on $\sqrt {n}(\widehat \theta - \theta_0) \stackrel{d}{\rightarrow}N(0,V)$ but $V$ cannot be calculated using the null and you have no option but to estimate $V$ and use the test $\frac{\sqrt{n}(\widehat \theta - \theta_0)}{\sqrt{\widehat V}}$ (e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_method_of_moments).

Comment: This brings up an interesting point about asymptotic behavior versus approximation. I think the problem gets fuzzy once there's a statement about $n$ being large. The teacher and I both understand that this means normal approximation can be used. But now I see that $n$ being large can also mean any estimator with the same asymptotic behavior can be used. I can make up an estimator like $\frac{\hat p}{\tanh(n+1)}$ and it would be equally acceptable. (Maybe normal approximation shouldn't be allowed in the first place if we're not given how far off we allow the final answer to be.)

Comment: In general, it would be better to know the finite sample properties but this theory can be intractable and problem dependent. On the other hand, the asymptotic theory is usually quite nice and general (and uses the powerful results of the law of large numbers and central limit theorem). For example, the asymptotic of instrumental variables (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumental_variable) is nice i.e. normal but the finite sample properties of instrumental variables are known to be bad (e.g. biased, moments don't exist...)

Comment: Having said that in many cases the asymptotics kick in quite quickly (and I think your problem is a case when this happens). For example, the rate of convergence is $\sqrt{n}$ so $|\widehat p -p_0|<O(\frac{1}{n})$. finally, yes, you can come up with another estimator but one way to compare is to through the variances i.e. the one with smaller variance is better.

Comment: I remember once seeing that the finite sample properties of the average of just four observations from a uniform distribution already look quite normal. You can probably do some simulations i.e. generate many times n observations, plot $\sqrt{n}(\widehat p-p_0)$ (I bet with small n it already looks normal).

Comment: Thank you. Your answer and comments have motivated me to look more into approximating the distribution of the sample mean with something more accurate than the normal distribution. Maybe I should go back to study the proof of CLT again in more detail.

Comment: For this particular problem you can figure out exactly the finite sample distribution because the problem comes from a binomial distribution. You can then compare this to a normal approximation. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation